# You shouldn't / You don't

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> A: We just discussed a few things.
>
> B: Right. Let me just make one thing very clear - you
> **shouldn't/don't** discuss my love life with them, alright?

If B is angry and orders A not to do that again, would "shouldn't" work or would that only sound like an advice? Would "don't" work fine?

Comment: You are right, shouldn't sounds more like a suggestion, but both work fine. The delivery is the most important thing to portray anger. "don't" sounds  more forceful and demanding and "do not" even more so... "Will not" is another alternative that I believe comes across as the most demanding, but again, it depends heavily on the delivery.

Comment: Might be better to leave out "you" here.  Use the imperative instead for a direct order - "Don't discuss my love life".